# WHOIS request with nodejs package failing

Tags: dns

I'm trying to do a bulk whois lookup of around 7000 domains.
I use the node js package [whois](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whois).

This worked while I tested with individual domains.

After I made a bulk request for batch of 50 domins, it stopped giving me data.

The response I get is as follows

```
% This is the RIPE Database query service.
% The objects are in RPSL format.
%
% The RIPE Database is subject to Terms and Conditions.
% See http://www.ripe.net/db/support/db-terms-conditions.pdf

% Note: this output has been filtered.
%       To receive output for a database update, use the "-B" flag.

%ERROR:101: no entries found
%
% No entries found in source RIPE.

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.91.2 (ANGUS)
```

But the request was run for existing domains.

What is going wrong? Now even individual requests are returning this for me. Am I blacklisted or something? Is there a rate limit?

Comment: Next time, you should ask RIPE and not us. They have a great support.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RonMaupin. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various regional internet registries have varying policies for bulk whois.

I know that RIPE has rate limiting for personal information; and may well have for queries in general.  You might find that one of RIPE's other interfaces is better suited for what you're doing, as it has many APIs, not just conventional whois.  See https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/db/support/querying-the-ripe-database

EDIT: RIPE is pretty clear about its policies and limits, see its [Query Reference Manual](https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/db/support/documentation/ripe-database-query-reference-manual#ref23), and [Acceptable Use Policy](https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/db/support/documentation/aup), which give the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @jonathanjo, It was very informative. I didn't even know what ripe was.